# Azure DevOps | Changing organization region - can't find US as an option

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking to change my Organization Region in Azure DevOps as explained here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-location

I did all the steps with the Virtual Support Agent but when it gives me the list of available regions it is missing "US" option - which I'm interested in.
My current region is West Europe.

[image: See here]

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: What is your current region?

Comment: it's West Europe

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej any idea what should I do next?

Comment: Being you I would create a ticket on [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21).